# Sklearn-classifier, issue with freez (pod pending in K8s)

Tags: python, kubernetes, scikit-learn, classification, mlrun

I got freez of Sklearn-classifier in MLRun (the job is still running after 5, 10, 20, ... minutes), see log output:

```
2023-02-21 13:50:15,853 [info] starting run training uid=e8e66defd91043dda62ae8b6795c74ea DB=http://mlrun-api:8080
2023-02-21 13:50:16,136 [info] Job is running in the background, pod: training-tgplm
```

see freez/pending issue on Web UI:

[image]

I used this source code and `classifier_fn.run(train_task, local=False)` generates freez:

```
# Import the Sklearn classifier function from the function hub
classifier_fn = mlrun.import_function('hub://sklearn-classifier')

# Prepare the parameters list for the training function
training_params = {"model_name": ['risk_xgboost'],              
              "model_pkg_class": ['sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingClassifier']}

# Define the training task, including the feature vector, label and hyperparams definitions
train_task = mlrun.new_task('training', 
                      inputs={'dataset': transactions_fv.uri},
                      params={'label_column': 'n4_pd30'}
                     )

train_task.with_hyper_params(training_params, strategy='list', selector='max.accuracy')

# Specify the cluster image
classifier_fn.spec.image = 'mlrun/mlrun'

# Run training
classifier_fn.run(train_task, local=False)
```

Did you have and solve the same issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the same issue and the problem was with different MLRun version between client side and server side. I had MLRun on client in version **1.2.1rc2** and server side in version **1.2.1** (these versions have different interfaces and it generates freez issue).

**Please, synch MLRun versions between client and server and it will works.**

BTW: Your part of code seems as this original sample here https://docs.mlrun.org/en/stable/feature-store/end-to-end-demo/02-create-training-model.html